# Zend Framework 2 - Composer - Manual installation of custom library is removed at install/update

Tags: php, zend-framework2, composer-php

I wrote an own library and included it manually in my `composer/autoload_namespaces.php` like I was told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13934480/1331671).

It works fine until I use the `install` or `update` command. Then this line is removed and I get an error when trying to use the lib.

Any ideas how to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestions you got in the other thread were not very good ones. Composer rewrites the autoload file with information from composer.json and thus you should never edit the php file directly. What you should do is add an autoload block to your composer.json.

For example:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Vendor\\Namespace\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Full docs on http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload

Comment: to link to the vendor dir you need to replace `src/` with `vendor/...`. important thing is not to set a slash before `vendor`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, i also updated the other answer to reflect the correct usage of composer.