# PHP Zend Framework 2 - Adding new validator

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Hi I'am new in ZF2 and just wanna to add new walidator for PESEL.
I create a ZendValidatePesel.php file in /library/Zend/Validator and copied the content from StringLength.php file. Changing class name of course for ZendValidatePesel.
Now, I'am trying to use it like:

```
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'ZendValidatePesel',
                        'options' => array(
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min' => 11,
                            'max' => 11,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
```

and got error:

```
Plik:
D:\xampp\htdocs\ZendHospital\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:529
Komunikat:
Zend\Validator\ValidatorPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for ZendValidatePesel
```

Please help me..

Comment: Generally, one wouldn't add custom validators - or any custom code - into the library/Zend/* space. Best to use either a module-specific namespace or a separate library. In either case, there are specific autoloading issues. For the latter case, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13934480/131824

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't add the validator (or anything else for that matter) into vendor namespaces. Instead put it somewhere within your application code. Don't know how your app is structured, but lets say `./module/YourModule/src/YourModule/Validator/ZendValidatePesel`.

Then reference your validator class with a full, qualified name, so following my guess it'd be something like:

```
'validators' => array(
    array(
        'name' => 'YourModule\Validator\ZendValidatePesel', 
        'options' => array(
            // ...
        ),
),
```

As far as I know that will directly instantiate the validator for you. Not-so-fun-fact: even if you'd register your validator there under the same name as the fqcn, it won't go through the `ValidatorPluginManager` -- something that I hope will be, or already is fixed in the framework (if it is somebody let me know, because it'd love to have validators with dependencies at last).